# Making Shape_area/Shape_length permanent in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I have two feature classes in a file geodatabase. Both have the dynamic `Shape_area` attribute. When I run an intersection tool it creates a new feature class with its own `Shape_area`.

Is there an easy way/tool/command to keep the original `Shape_area` attributes as well?

Or do I have to create a new attribute and then pass the `Shape_area` values?

Or maybe the easiest way would be to create a tool in `ModelBuilder`?

Comment: Thanks! I knew there has to be an easy way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new non dynamic area field using the [Calculate Geometry Attributes (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm) tool.